# How to produce "app_exception" event in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to log different default events using **Google Analytics** for Firebase. I have added a line in my code to make the app crash. App crashes when I press toast button due to the presence of throw inside `onClickListener`. As per Firebase documentation, the crash should log default "app_exception". But I am not able to see that event in my events dashboard. Please suggest alternate ways of logging this event.

My Code is as follows:

```
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        mFirebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
        bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("App_launched","Launch sucessfull");
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT,bundle);
        toastBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Toast_launched","New Toast");
                mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("Toast_launched",bundle);
                mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(MainActivity.this,"Dummy Screen",null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Toast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("age","21");
                throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement fabric https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install and connect it with firebase in order to log events like crashes.

https://get.fabric.io/roadmap